# Destructuring JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have a JavaSCript object, **person**, that contains *id*, *name*, *phone* and *address* properties. I want to modify the property names and put them into a new object, **personData**. Can this be done in 1 step?:

Step 1 (create a var for each property with different names):

```
var { id:personId, 
      name:personName, 
      phone:personPhone, 
      address:personAddress
   } = person;
```

Step 2 (create a new object containing those vars):

```
var personData = {
    personId,
    personName,
    personPhone,
    personAddress
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new object containing those vars:

```
var personData = {
    personId: person.id,
    personName: person.name,
    personPhone: person.phone,
    personAddress: person.addres
}
```

Comment: holydragon, your Step 2 is what I was looking for. Your Step 1 seems superfluous, though. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it. Thank you.

Comment: holydragon, see my comment. Step 2 answers my question. Can you edit and remove step 1? Then I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want the spread operator, not destructuring.

```
var personData = { ...person, name: 'New name', phone: 'New phone' }
```

This creates a new object personData with all the properties of person and either adds or replaces the other properties listed.

Comment: This seems promising. However, it seems to allow you to change the property values when creating that new object and/or to add new properties. Is there a way to actually remove an existing property (either by changing its name or removing it and adding a different one)?